# Python flask for loop

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to accomplish dynamically creating a html table populated by a a dict that is created from a sqlite query. each row has it's own approve and deny button, which will execute a query when clicked. When one of the buttons is clicked, the next time that page is reloaded, those buttons will be disabled. My problem is that when I click one of the approve or deny buttons, even though that onclick passes the id associated with that row so the query can update that row in the database, all of the rows in the database get updated on that one button click. Here is my code.

```
<table border='1' align="center">
    {% for post in posts %}

        {% if post.approved == "True" or post.approved == "False" %}
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>{{post.id}}</label>
                        <h1 id ='grill1'>{{post.photoName}}</h1>
                        <span>
                            <img id = 'photo1' src='{{post.photo}}' alt="Smiley face" height="200" width="200">
                        </span><br>
                        <h5 id ='blurb1'>
                            {{post.blurb}}
                        </h5>
                        <br>
                        <div style=" padding:10px; text-align:center;">
                            <input type="button" id='approved{{post.id}}'  value="Approve" name="approve" onclick="window.location='/approve/{{post.id}}';"> 
                            <input type="button" id='denied{{post.id}}' value="Deny" onclick="window.location='/deny/{{post.id}}';"><br>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <script>
                document.getElementById("approved"+{{post.id}}).disabled = true;
                document.getElementById("denied"+{{post.id}}).disabled = true;
                </script>
        {% else %}
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>{{post.id}}</label>
                        <h1 id ='grill1'>{{post.photoName}}</h1>
                        <span>
                            <img id = 'photo1' src='{{post.photo}}' alt="Smiley face" height="200" width="200">
                        </span><br>
                        <h5 id ='blurb1'>
                            {{post.blurb}}
                        </h5>
                        <br>
                        <div style=" padding:10px; text-align:center;">
                            <input type="button" id='approved{{post.id}}'  value="Approve" name="approve" onclick="window.location='/approve/{{post.id}}';"> 
                            <input type="button" id='denied{{post.id}}' value="Deny" onclick="window.location='/deny/{{post.id}}';"><br>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <script>
                document.getElementById("approved"+{{post.id}}).disabled = false;
                document.getElementById("denied"+{{post.id}}).disabled = false;
                </script>
        {% endif %}

    <!--<tr>
        <td>
            <label>{{post.id}}</label>
            <h1 id ='grill1'>{{post.photoName}}</h1>
            <span>
                <img id = 'photo1' src='{{post.photo}}' alt="Smiley face" height="200" width="200">
            </span><br>
            <h5 id ='blurb1'>
                {{post.blurb}}
            </h5>
            <br>
            <div style=" padding:10px; text-align:center;">
                <input type="button" id='approved'  value="Approve" name="approve" onclick="window.location='/approve/{{post.id}}';"> 
                <input type="button" id='denied' value="Deny" onclick="window.location='/deny/{{post.id}}';"><br>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>-->
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

and corresponding function:

```
@app.route('/approve/<int:post_id>')
def approve(post_id):
    con = connect_db('ugly_grills.db')
    con.execute('UPDATE grills SET approved = "True" WHERE ID = id;')
    con.commit()
    cur = con.execute('SELECT * FROM grills;')
    posts = [dict(fName=row[0], lName=row[1], email=row[2], phone=row[3], photoName=row[4],  photo=row[5], blurb=row[6], id=row[7], approved=row[8], vote=row[9]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    con.close()
    return render_template("approval.html", posts=posts)
```

Comment: what items do you want to show in each table's row?
in your code you will always a table with a single column. I don't think thats what u want

Comment: I want to show it like this, with a break after each one.
<label>ID<label>
<h1>name</h1>
<img></img>
<h5>Description</h5>

Comment: can you add few items of `posts` that you want to render??

Comment: Can you elaborate? Are you asking if I can add more items to the posts when I do render_template("...",posts=post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this and tell me if you had issues.

```
<table border='1' align="center">
    <tr>
        <th>Post ID</th>
        <th>Photo Name</th>
        <th>Photo</th>
        <th>Blurb!!!</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
{% for post in posts %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ post.id }}</td>
        <td>
            <h1 class="grill1">{{ post.photoName }}</h1>
        </td>
        <td><img id="photo-{{post.id}}" src="{{ post.photo }}" alt="Smiley face" height="200" width="200"></td>
        <td>
            <h5 class="blurb1">{{ post.blurb }}</h5>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button"{% if not post.approved %} disabled{% endif %} value="Approve" name="approve" onclick="window.location='/approve/{{post.id}}';"
            <input type="button"{% if not post.approved %} disabled{% endif %} value="Deny" name="deny" onclick="window.location='/deny/{{post.id}}';"
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

**UPDATE:**
Your problem is where you execute update query.

You are selecting the record value by the 'id' (string) as it's id, not the integer ID which is sent to function by post_id. that's why your update is applied to all of records.

Do this instead:

```
import sqlite3

@app.route('/approve/<int:post_id>')
def approve(post_id):
    con = sqlite3.connect('ugly_grills.db')
    con.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('UPDATE grills SET approved = "True" WHERE ID=?', (post_id,))
    # ------------------------------------------- DON'T FORGET THIS COMMA ^
    con.commit()
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM grills')
    posts = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template("approval.html", posts=posts)
```

Comment: What the point of adding part {% if loop.first %} inside loop? If you move it outside {% for %} you will save time not checking for condition on every cycle.